# Showing nice indentation of Python code

Tags: fancyvrb, pygments, pythontex

I use `pythontex` to typeset my Python listings. I'd like to have some kind of L-shaped lines, like the ones I added in the image below to clearly exhibit the indentation level of every line of code.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{pygments}[frame=single]{python}
def f(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return f(n-1)

print(f(4))
\end{pygments}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want this with `pythontex` or any code package is fine?

Comment: Well `pythontex` would be really nice as it is part of my workflow. In addition, a solution with `pythontex` could take advantage of Python to parse and place, say, tikz code. But any code package would be fine.

Comment: Ok. Yes it would be better with your package, but I was asking in case it wasn't possible with that one (I'm not saying it's not). :D

Comment: `pythontex` uses Pygments to do the highlighting. In principle, it would be possible to post-process the Pygments output based on indentation level, and add in the lines. However, that might get complicated, and might fail for expressions that break across multiple lines unless you were really careful. The "proper" way to do this would probably be in Pygments, but even there, I'm not sure if the (default) lexer has enough information to do this in the general case.

Comment: While this might be possible another way is just to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) and use 4 spaces per indentation level. Then no extra lines are necessary and it looks much closer to what the code looks like in an external editor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you for very interesting problem.

You can use following macros:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\def\makeL{\vbox\bgroup \global\linenum=0 
   \let\FancyVerbFormatLine=\Lformat \let\next=}
\def\sxdef#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}

\newcount\spacenum  \newcount\linenum  \newcount\linenumA  \newcount\tmpnum
\def\Lformat#1{\global\spacenum=0
   \ifx\end#1\end\else \LformatA#1\end\fi
   \global\advance\linenum by1
   \sxdef{L:\the\spacenum}{\the\linenum}%
   \tmpnum=\spacenum \def\Llist{}\let\Ldraw=\relax
   \loop
      \advance\tmpnum by-1
      \ifnum\tmpnum>-1
         \expandafter\ifx\csname L:\the\tmpnum\endcsname \relax \else
            \advance\spacenum by-\tmpnum
            \linenumA=\linenum  
            \advance\linenumA by-\csname L:\the\tmpnum\endcsname
            \edef\Llist{\Ldraw{\the\spacenum}{\the\linenumA}\Llist}%
            \spacenum=\tmpnum
         \fi
   \repeat
   \let\Ldraw=\LdrawX
   \csname FV@ObeyTabs\endcsname{\rlap{\Llist}#1}}
\def\LformatA#1{%
   \ifx#1\fspace \global\advance\spacenum by1 \let\next=\LformatA
   \else \let\next=\formatlineB \fi
   \ifx#1\end \let\next=\relax \fi
   \next
}
\def\formatlineB#1\end{}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\fspace\expandafter{\csname FV@Space\endcsname}

\def\LdrawX#1#2{%
   \dimen0=.5em \dimen0=#1\dimen0 \advance\dimen0 by-.4em  
   \dimen1=\normalbaselineskip \dimen1=#2\dimen1 \advance\dimen1 by-1ex
   \message{(#1,#2)=(\the\dimen0,\the\dimen1,\the\normalbaselineskip)}%
   \pdfliteral{q 1 g .5 G .9963 0 0 .9963 2 2 cm 
      0 0 \ptdim0 \ptdim1 re f \ptdim0 0 m 0 0 l 0 \ptdim1 l S Q}%
   \dimen0=.5em \kern#1\dimen0
}
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}
\def\ptdim#1{\expandafter\ignorept\the\dimen#1 }

\begin{document}
\makeL{
\begin{pygments}[frame=single]{python}
class enum:
  def __init__(self,level=1):
    self.content=list()   
    self.level=level
  def __repr__(self):
    ret = "[["
    for x in self.parse():
      ret += repr(x)
    return ret+"]]"
  def parse(self):
    itemcounter = 0   
    subbullets=enum(self.level+1)
    parsed=list()
    for item in self.content:
      itemcounter += 1
      try:
        if item[0][0] in [PENITEM, ENITEM]:
      except IndexError:
        self.fail("foobar")
#ende
\end{pygments}
}
\end{document}
```

This means that you must write:

```
\makeL{
\begin{pygments}[frame=single]{python}
... your code
\end{pygments}
}
```

And you get:

[image: L example]

Of course, `pygments` environment needs to run `pythontex example` after TeXing in order to syntax highlighting.

**Explanation** The `\makeL` macro redefines `\FancyVerbFormatLine` used for verbatim output by `pygments` environment as `\Lformat`. This macro counts the line and counts the number of spaces in the front of the line and saves it as macro `\L:num-spaces` with the contents `line-number`.
Then the list of L symbols is stored for current line into `\Llist` macro. Each L symbol is represented in the form `\Ldraw{right}{up}` where `right` is the width of L (the number of the columns) and `up` is the height of the L (the number of the lines). Finally, the L symbols (i. e. `\Ldraw`) are processed using `\pdfiteral`.

Limitation: this macro expects that no page breaks are in the middle of the code. But a skillful macro programmer can add such feature as an exercise.

Dependences: you need not any additional package. You can process the macros by `pdflatex` or `lualatex` or `xelatex`. When `xelatex` is used then you must define:

```
\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}
```

**Edit** The second version of my macros below (at the end of this post) simplifies the input and allows page breaks in the middle of the code.

The input can be prepared as normally in `Verbatim` (from fancyvrb) or `pygments` (from pythontex) environments. If the new key-value pair `indent=L` is present then the L indentations is calculated and printed else these environments work normally. Example:

```
\begin{pygments}[frame=single, indent=L]{python}
... your code
\end{pygments}
```

or

```
\begim{Verbatim}[frame=single, indent=L]
... your code
\end{pygments}
```

In order to allow page breaking we must decompose the large `L` (over more lines) to one or more `I`s ended by small `L`:

```
XXXXXXXX
I XXXXXX
I I XXXX
I L XXXX
L XXXXXX
```

Then we can print Is and Ls in each line separately and the code can be broken to more lines. There is only one little problem: we must know the indentation of the following line when printing current line in order to decide if L or I must be printed. Fortunately, the `fancyverb.sty` keeps current line in the box and it print this box after reading next line. So, we can calculate the indentation of the next line and print the box from previous line overlapped by Ls or Is. This work is done by `\Lbox` macro (instead original `\box` in the `fancyvrb.sty` macros). And `\Lbox` uses `\Llist` calculated from previous line where is a list of `\Ldraw` macros desribed above. And `\Ldraw` macro draws L or I simply by:

```
\def\Ldraw{\ifnum\tmpnum<\spacenum \expandafter\LdrawI \else \expandafter\LdrawL\fi}
```

where `\tmpnum` includes the current column number and `\spacenum` the number of spaces of the next line.

The example follows. My macros must be included *after* loading `pythontex.sty` or `fancyvrb.sty` because some internal macros from `fancyvrb.sty` are re-defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}  

\def\sxdef#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}
\def\ptdim#1{\expandafter\ignorept\the\dimen#1 }

\newcount\spacenum  \newcount\linenum  \newcount\linenumA  \newcount\tmpnum

\def\Lcountspaces#1{\spacenum=0 \ifx\end#1\end\else \LcountspacesA#1\end\fi}
\def\LcountspacesA#1{%
   \ifx#1\fspace \advance\spacenum by1 \let\next=\LcountspacesA
   \else \let\next=\LcountspacesB \fi
   \ifx#1\end \let\next=\relax \fi
   \next
}
\def\LcountspacesB#1\end{}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\fspace\expandafter{\csname FV@Space\endcsname}

\def\Lbegin{\global\linenum=0 \gdef\Llist{}}

\def\Lformat#1{%
   \global\advance\linenum by1
   \sxdef{L:\the\spacenum}{\the\linenum}%
   \tmpnum=\spacenum \gdef\Llist{}\let\Ldraw=\relax
   \loop
      \advance\tmpnum by-1
      \ifnum\tmpnum>-1
         \expandafter\ifx\csname L:\the\tmpnum\endcsname \relax \else
            \advance\spacenum by-\tmpnum
            \linenumA=\linenum  
            \advance\linenumA by-\csname L:\the\tmpnum\endcsname
            \xdef\Llist{\Ldraw{\the\spacenum}{\the\linenumA}\Llist}%
            \spacenum=\tmpnum
         \fi
   \repeat  
   \csname FV@ObeyTabs\endcsname{#1}}

\def\Lbox#1{\hbox to\hsize{\rlap{\box#1}%
  \kern\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname \kern\csname FV@XLeftMargin\endcsname
  \setbox0=\hbox{\csname FV@LeftListFrame\endcsname}\kern\wd0
  \tmpnum=0 \Llist\hss}}

\def\Ldraw{\ifnum\tmpnum<\spacenum \expandafter\LdrawI \else \expandafter\LdrawL\fi}
\def\LdrawL#1#2{%
   \dimen0=.5em \dimen0=#1\dimen0 \advance\dimen0 by-.4em
   \dimen1=1.4ex
   \dimen2=.5ex 
   \pdfliteral{q \Lshape\space .9963 0 0 .9963 \ptdim2 \ptdim2 cm
      \ptdim0 0 m 0 0 l 0 \ptdim1 l S Q}%
   \LdrawE{#1}}

\def\LdrawI#1#2{%
   \dimen0=-.85ex
   \dimen1=\normalbaselineskip
   \dimen2=.5ex
   \pdfliteral{q \Lshape\space .9963 0 0 .9963 \ptdim2 \ptdim0 cm
      0 0 m 0 \ptdim1 l S Q}%
   \LdrawE{#1}}

\def\LdrawE#1{\dimen0=.5em \kern#1\dimen0 \advance\tmpnum by#1 }

\csname define@key\endcsname{FV}{indent}{\csname FV@indent@#1\endcsname}
\sdef{FV@indent@L}{\let\FancyVerbFormatLine=\Lformat}

\def\Lshape{1 g .5 G 1 w 1 j 1 J} % .5 gray 1bp width rounded ends, rounded corner

%%%%%%% re-definition of internal macros from fancyvrb.sty
{\makeatletter
\gdef\FV@ListProcessLine@i#1{\Lcountspaces{#1}%  <--- added by P.O.
  \hbox{%
    \ifvoid\@labels\else
      \hbox to \z@{\kern\@totalleftmargin\box\@labels\hss}%
    \fi
    \FV@ListProcessLine{#1}}%
  \let\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@ii}
\gdef\FV@ListProcessLine@ii#1{\Lcountspaces{#1}%  <--- added by P.O. 
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\FV@ListProcessLine{#1}%
  \let\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iii}
\gdef\FV@ListProcessLine@iii#1{\Lcountspaces{#1}% <--- added by P.O.
  {\advance\interlinepenalty\clubpenalty\penalty\interlinepenalty}%  
  \Lbox\@tempboxa                              % <--- Lbox by P.O.
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\FV@ListProcessLine{#1}% 
  \let\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iv}
\gdef\FV@ListProcessLine@iv#1{\Lcountspaces{#1}%  <--- added by P.O. 
  \penalty\interlinepenalty
  \Lbox\@tempboxa                              % <--- Lbox by P.O.
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\FV@ListProcessLine{#1}}%
\gdef\FV@ListProcessLastLine{\spacenum=0 %     % <--- added by P.O.  
  \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iv
    {\advance\interlinepenalty\widowpenalty\penalty\interlinepenalty}%
    \Lbox\@tempboxa                            % <--- Lbox by P.O.
  \else
    \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iii
      {\advance\interlinepenalty\widowpenalty
        \advance\interlinepenalty\clubpenalty
        \penalty\interlinepenalty}%
      \Lbox\@tempboxa                         % <--- Lbox by P.O.
    \else
      \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@i
        \FV@Error{Empty verbatim environment}{}%
         \FV@ProcessLine{}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\gdef\FVB@Verbatim{\Lbegin\FV@VerbatimBegin\FV@Scan} % <--- Lbegin added by P.O.
\gdef\@begin@pygments@hook{\Lbegin}
}
%%%%%%%%%%% end of re-definition

\begin{document}

Testing:

\begin{pygments}[frame=single, indent=L]{python}
def f(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return f(n-1)

print(f(4)) 
\end{pygments}

Next code:\vskip10cm

\begin{pygments}[frame=single,indent=L]{python}
class enum:
  def __init__(self,level=1):
    self.content=list()
    self.level=level
  def __repr__(self):
    ret = "[["
    for x in self.parse():
      ret += repr(x)
    return ret+"]]"  
  def parse(self):
    itemcounter = 0
    subbullets=enum(self.level+1)
    parsed=list()    
    for item in self.content:
      itemcounter += 1
      try:
        if item[0][0] in [PENITEM, ENITEM]:
      except IndexError:
        self.fail("foobar")
\end{pygments}

\end{document}
```

Because of the `\Lshape` macro (gray, roundend corners), the detail of the result looks like:

[image: lcode2]

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. This is really an interesting approach since it is "generic". However, I was hoping for a solution that would survive page breaks (that's where my students sometimes forget how many indentations they should read). Would you be that skillful macro programmer? `;-)`

Comment: @cjorssen OK, I'll try it. If I understand the rules here, I have about 5 days for this...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. This could clearly be part of `fancyvrb` itself @Herbert.

Comment: When you have a minute, could you please explain the magic you use to actually draw the lines? I have some issues when margin get changed (say in an `enumerate` environment) that I'd like to be able to adjust. Thanks

Comment: @cjorssen Do you mean what `\pdfliteral` does? I don't fully understand your question. Please, sent me an email with more specification. It is better to me to use email than this forum for communication.

Comment: Ok, I'll send you an email and report back here (if you don't).

Answer (score 14):

I know what I did here is cheating. Also I know that this is far from a final solution, as it currently still requires the code to be entered twice into the file. But this could for example be simplified by loading the code from an external file all along. Think of this as a concept/suggestion of approaching the issue differently.

What this code basically does is it replaces each leading double space with a "|_".The "_" part of the previous line gets erased (covered) when the next line prints it's "|_". Finally, the pygments

It might not be the most elegant or sophisticated way, but it saves you a lot of bother. Of course this is not the ultimate implementation The result looks like this

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tikz}
%% Lua-side code
%this goes through the lines of the code and reads how many "doubles spaces are leading each line
\begin{luacode}
function readindent ( line ) 
    if not string.find(line, "drawindent") then
      indent = math.floor(string.len(string.match(line,"^%s*") or "") / 2)
      line = "~\\\\"..string.rep("\\pycodehook",indent)..""
    end
    return ( line )
end 
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\ignore[1]{(#1)}
\newenvironment{drawindent}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",readindent, "readindent")}}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer","readindent")}}
\newcommand*\pycodehook{\rlap{\smash{~\tikz{                        %this draws a hook in each and every code line and erases hooks from the lines above
  \fill[fill=gray]  (-0.24pt,0pt) rectangle (1ex,1\baselineskip);
  \fill[fill=white]  (0.24pt,.5pt) rectangle (1ex,1.5\baselineskip);
  }}}\phantom{\ttfamily{~~}}}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][0pt][t]{0pt}%
\begin{drawindent}
class enum:
  def __init__(self,level=1):
    self.content=list()
    self.level=level
  def __repr__(self):
    ret = "[["
    for x in self.parse():
      ret += repr(x)
    return ret+"]]"
  def parse(self):
    itemcounter = 0
    subbullets=enum(self.level+1)
    parsed=list()
    for item in self.content:
      itemcounter += 1
      try:
        if item[0][0] in [PENITEM, ENITEM]:
      except IndexError:
        self.fail("foobar")
#ende
}
\end{drawindent}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}%
\begin{pygments}[frame=single]{python}
class enum:
  def __init__(self,level=1):
    self.content=list()
    self.level=level
  def __repr__(self):
    ret = "[["
    for x in self.parse():
      ret += repr(x)
    return ret+"]]"
  def parse(self):
    itemcounter = 0
    subbullets=enum(self.level+1)
    parsed=list()
    for item in self.content:
      itemcounter += 1
      try:
        if item[0][0] in [PENITEM, ENITEM]:
      except IndexError:
        self.fail("foobar")
#ende
\end{pygments}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

For Completeness: some of the code is taken from here: [Treat environment content as String, replace substrings and interpret afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265901/treat-environment-content-as-string-replace-substrings-and-interpret-afterwards/265913)

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. This is really an interesting approach. Unfortunately, `luatex` is not part of my workflow for that kind of job. I'm afraid I think I'll adopt wipet's way of doing it. But, again, thank you!

Comment: I think that is a good choice