# How can I use scintillua lexers to replace minted or listings with luatex?

Tags: listings, luatex, verbatim, minted

[Scintilla](http://scintilla.org/) is a text editor. [Scintillua](http://foicica.com/scintillua/README.html) adds dynamic Lua LPeg lexers to Scintilla for [multiple languages](https://github.com/rgieseke/scintillua/tree/master/lexers). [According to the documentation](http://foicica.com/scintillua/manual.html), Scintillua can be used as a library:

> Using Scintillua as a Lua Library
>
> In order to use Scintillua as a Lua library, simply place the lexers/
>   directory in your Lua path (or modify Lua’s package.path accordingly),
>   require() the library and load() a lexer, and call that lexer’s lex()
>   function. Here is an example interactive Lua session doing this:
>
> ```
> $> lua
> Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> > lexer_path = '/home/mitchell/code/scintillua/lexers/?.lua'
> > package.path = package.path..';'..lexer_path
> > c = require('lexer').load('ansi_c')
> > tokens = c:lex('int void main() { return 0; }')
> > for i = 1, #tokens, 2 do print(tokens[i], tokens[i+1]) end
> type    4
> ansi_c_whitespace   5
> type    9
> ansi_c_whitespace   10
> identifier  14
> operator    15
> operator    16
> ansi_c_whitespace   17
> operator    18
> ansi_c_whitespace   19
> keyword 25
> ansi_c_whitespace   26
> number  27
> operator    28
> ansi_c_whitespace   29
> operator    30
> ```

I was wondering if it would be possible to use those lexers as a lua replacement for `minted` or `listings`? In addition, it seems that Scintillua supports code folding that could be used to underline code structure as in an [old question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249755/8425). What would be the basic code for interacting between `TeX` and lua (catcodes, etc.)?

Comment: This isn’t trivially possible, because neither minted nor listings accept such a lexer input. You’ll need to write your own package that accepts lexer input and formats the tokens.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed. I'd like to have a skeleton showing how it is possible to work on lua side, including the verbatim part. Then I can work on and elaborate.

Comment: @cjorssen: In ConTeXt, passing the verbatim part to lua is trivial. See [manipulating verbatim text](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Manipulating_verbatim_text) on the ConTeXt wiki. Something similar should also exist for  You will need to write a function that takes the lua table returned by `lex()` and generates the appropriate TeX code.

Comment: I took this as an exercice to learn how to do `TeX` without `TeX` in `luatex` (I don't want to deal with verbatim at `TeX` level). Development is [here](https://github.com/cjorssen/scintillua-verb), really early stage...